# How to fix javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: DQ not bound exception in Spring JMS?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-jms, hornetq

This problem occurs when I am trying to send message to receiver from sender. I uses HornetQ JMS server to send message. How can I fix this problem?

> WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization -
>   cancelling refresh attempt
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'topicDestination' defined in class path
>   resource [springconfig.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested
>   exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: DQ not bound

Answer (score 0):

I try this code in Springconfig.xml file later

property name="jndiName" value="queue/DQ"

and also edit 
hornetq-2.4.0.Final\config\stand-alone\shared-store\hornetq-jms.xml
and add queue in hornetq-jms.xml  file

--queue name="taxQueue" 
     entry name="/queue/DQ"

it will run correctly.